# Copy tmp file fast

Tags: ios, swift, download, nsdata, nsurlsession

I was wondering, if there is a different and faster solution to the following problem. I am downloading a file with `NSURLSession`. By default (I guess?) the downloaded file is stored in the tmp folder. Then I need to copy this file to the cache folder. At the moment I am using this code for my approach (in the `didFinishDownloading` function)

```
if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfURL: sourceUrl) {
        fileData.writeToURL(destinationURL, atomically: true)   // true
        print(destinationURL.path!)
        }
```

However, as my file is pretty large, this takes a while. 
Is there a different option on copying this file to the cache folder?
Or is it possible to download a file directly to the Cache folder using the `NSURLSession`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *copying* the file you can simply *move* it to the
desired location:

```
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(sourceURL, toURL: destinationURL)
} catch let err as NSError {
    print(err.localizedDescription)
}
```

This would be much faster because only directory entries in the
file system are modified, but no data is actually copied.

**Swift 3 update:**

```
do {
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: that makes sense, and it works! thank you for this solution